# Codeigniter upload unallowed file not producing error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am running into an issue using this simple Codeigniter image upload based on the examples in CI documentation.

What is going wrong:

1.) If an incorrect file type is uploaded, it does not return an error. It sets all of my post variables to null and continues to process.

2.) I am able to upload .sql and some (but not all) .exe files, even wityh the allowed filetypes limited to jpg, gif and png.

So, it is not the commonly reported problem of rejecting allowed filetypes, but being too permissive, and not returning an error when it should.

```
    $photo = $this->input->post("photo");

    $config['upload_path'] = './profile_img/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){  
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
        {
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->session->set_userdata("message", $error);
                header("Location: /page/account");
        }
        else
        {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $photo = $upload_data['file_name'];
        }
    }

    $data = array(
        'first_name' => $this->input->post("first_name"),
        'last_name' => $this->input->post("last_name"),
        'username' => $this->input->post("username"),
        'default_meeting_duration' => $this->input->post("default_meeting_duration"),
        'notification_type' => $this->input->post("notification_type"),
        'photo' => $photo
    );

    $this->user_model->update($data, $this->ion_auth->get_user_id());
    $this->session->set_userdata("message", "Account Settings Saved");
    header("Location: /page/account");
```

Comment: remove first if condition then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, the solution was in inserting exit() after the first redirect within the error condition.

Apparently, the behavior was such that even if an error condition was found, the redirect was ignored, and the rest of the script executed. Clearly a bug in CI that was baffling and difficult to find.